# Copy and preserve formatting when copy pasting from WhatsApp web to any editor

Tags: copy-paste, format, chat, whatsapp

I have WhatsApp open in a browser using WhatsApp web. There are messages that I receive that have formatting included, say bolding of a few words, italics, underlines etc. Now I want to copy the message from the WhatsApp chat thread and paste it to Wordpress blogs retaining the formatting as is. However, when I copy from the WhatsApp and paste it outside (in a blog or in a text editor like Sublime, TextEdit, Microsoft Word etc.), none of them are preserving the formatting. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to open the necessary chat in WhatsApp web in a browser, then open the rendered code using "Inspect Element" and copy the html code from there. That will have the bold/italic tags etc. as needed.